# Gradle can't get dependencies from nexus repository?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

my jenkins job throws this exception, while trying to connect to nexus repository i presume, anyone has any thoughts on that ? I can see it being mentioned in multiple other topics, but didn't found any solution in there for my issue.

```
The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':<dir>-web:xxx'.
```

and later

```
13:10:29  * What went wrong:
13:10:29  Execution failed for task ':xx-web:qqq'.
13:10:29  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':xx-web:qqq'.
13:10:29     > Could not resolve mt.com.bbb.xx:xx-commons:0.0.9.
13:10:29       Required by:
13:10:29           project :xxx-web
13:10:29        > Could not resolve mt.com.bbb.xx:xx-commons:0.0.9.
13:10:29           > Could not parse POM http://<service>/repository/maven-public/.../xx-commons/0.0.9/xx-commons-0.0.9.pom
13:10:29              > The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

after build I see in the cache this file - (with clear wrong <\hr> tag)

```
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<hr><center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

and when trying to simply `wget` it from the host I get

```
root@jenkins-agent-t4dq3:/home/jenkins/workspace/# wget http://<url>/repository/maven-public/mt/com/xx/yy/0.0.9/yy-0.0.9.pom
--2020-03-10 06:40:14--  http://<url>/repository/maven-public/mt/com/xx/yy/0.0.9/xx-0.0.9.pom
Resolving <url> (<url>)... <ip>
Connecting to <url> (<url>)|<ip>|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 308 Permanent Redirect
2020-03-10 06:40:14 ERROR 308: Permanent Redirect.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Gradle about the repo location - Note that you need to figure out the correct location to use, `localhost:8081` is probably not right:

```
repositories {
    maven {
          url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465358-How-do-I-configure-my-Gradle-build-to-download-artifacts-from-Nexus-

Comment: hmm I already had it in build.gradle `repositories {
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
~             url "https://<my_url>/repository/maven-public/"
              credentials {
                  username nexusUsername
                  password nexusPassword
              }
          }`

Comment: think the real issue is this part `The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>`

Comment: No, that means you have an invalid URL in your repository location and you're getting back invalid HTML when Gradle tries to fetch your repo. Also, how are we supposed to know what is in your build.gradle file if you don't post it?

Comment: yeah, you were right, the issue was this url, but I had to put `https` otherwise it throws 308 redirect or 401 unauthorized *_*